# Select single directed acyclic graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to neo4j and I'm trying to extract a single, directed acyclic subgraph from from a graph in such a way as to be able to iterate over the resulting graph (or the collection of nodes and paths) and keep track of layers in which each node would reside (where `layers` are based on *the number of hops from the* ***nearest*** *root node*).  Is this possible in cypher?  I'm using the REST api.

The example datastructure I have is something like the following subgraph, where `A` and `H` would be the 'root' nodes:

```
A -+ B -+ D
     |    
     +   
H -+ C -+ E
     |
     +
     F


S*
```

`B` and `C` would each be layer 1 and `D`, `E`, `F` would be layer 2.  `A` and `H` have a `:SUBGRAPH_ENTER` relation to `S*` and all nodes in the subgraph I want have the relation `:MEMBER_OF_SUBGRAPH` to `S*`

The following query will return the subgraph (piecemeal) I want, however, I'm not sure how to go about ordering the nodes in the paths.

```
        MATCH p = (n)-[r:ARROW_TO*]-(t)-[:SUBGRAPH_ENTER]-(s)
        where
        (n)-[:MEMBER_OF_SUBGRAPH]->(s)
        RETURN p
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

If you create your sample acyclic graph with these 2 queries:

```
CREATE (s:Subgraph),
  (a:Foo {id:'A'}), (b:Foo {id:'B'}), (c:Foo {id:'C'}), (d:Foo {id:'D'}), (e:Foo {id:'E'}), (f:Foo {id:'F'}), (h:Foo {id:'H'}), 
  (a)-[:ARROW_TO]->(b)-[:ARROW_TO]->(d),
  (h)-[:ARROW_TO]->(c)-[:ARROW_TO]->(e),
  (b)-[:ARROW_TO]->(c)-[:ARROW_TO]->(f),
  (a)<-[:SUBGRAPH_ENTER]-(s),
  (h)<-[:SUBGRAPH_ENTER]-(s);

MATCH (f:Foo), (s:Subgraph)
CREATE (f)-[:MEMBER_OF_SUBGRAPH]->(s);
```

then this query will return the subgraph nodes, ordered by distance from the nearest root:

```
MATCH p=(s)-[:SUBGRAPH_ENTER]->(root)-[:ARROW_TO*]->(leaf)
WHERE (NOT (leaf)-[:ARROW_TO]->()) AND ALL(n IN NODES(p)[1..] WHERE (n)-[:MEMBER_OF_SUBGRAPH]->(s))
WITH s, NODES(p)[2..] AS nodes
WITH s, REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(nodes)-1) | s + {node: nodes[i], dist: i+1}) AS data
UNWIND data AS datum
RETURN s, datum.node AS node, MIN(datum.dist) AS distance
ORDER BY distance;
```

The `WHERE` clause filters out paths that are partial or have nodes from other subgraphs.
The first `WITH` clause collects the nodes in each path starting after the `root` node.
The second `WITH` clause generates a collection of node/distance pairs for each node in the first collection.
The `UNWIND` transforms the latter collection into data rows, for processing by the `MIN` aggregation function.

Here are the results:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| s          | node             | distance |
+------------------------------------------+
| Node[38]{} | Node[41]{id:"C"} | 1        |
| Node[38]{} | Node[40]{id:"B"} | 1        |
| Node[38]{} | Node[44]{id:"F"} | 2        |
| Node[38]{} | Node[43]{id:"E"} | 2        |
| Node[38]{} | Node[42]{id:"D"} | 2        |
+------------------------------------------+
```

### Including the root nodes

If you want to include the root nodes in the output, this query will do that:

```
MATCH p=(s)-[:SUBGRAPH_ENTER]->(root)-[:ARROW_TO*]->(leaf)
WHERE (NOT (leaf)-[:ARROW_TO]->()) AND ALL (n IN NODES(p)[1..] WHERE (n)-[:MEMBER_OF_SUBGRAPH]->(s))
WITH s, NODES(p)[1..] AS nodes
WITH s, REDUCE(s =[], i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(nodes)-1)| s + { node: nodes[i], dist: i }) AS data
UNWIND data AS datum
RETURN s, datum.node AS node, MIN(datum.dist) AS distance
ORDER BY distance;
```

Here are the results:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| s         | node             | distance |
+-----------------------------------------+
| Node[6]{} | Node[7]{id:"A"}  | 0        |
| Node[6]{} | Node[13]{id:"H"} | 0        |
| Node[6]{} | Node[8]{id:"B"}  | 1        |
| Node[6]{} | Node[9]{id:"C"}  | 1        |
| Node[6]{} | Node[10]{id:"D"} | 2        |
| Node[6]{} | Node[12]{id:"F"} | 2        |
| Node[6]{} | Node[11]{id:"E"} | 2        |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hey, nice!  How can I include `A` and `H` and omit `S*` in the result?  (also, I'll upvote if you can explain the operations in the `with` and `unwind` clauses, or link to somewhere that does :))

Comment: If you get rid of the `S*` node from the result, then the results of multiple subgraphs would be jumbled together. But, if you really wanted to do that, simply remove `s, ` from the `RETURN line.